# How to show render-stamp for arbitrary values?

Tags: rendering, customization, image

Is it possible to take arbitrary properties and display them in the render stamp as some other software do.

[image]
(Click the image for larger version)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

While Blender has no build-in support for this feature. You can do this using Python:

Add a script into your file, call it `stamp_init.py` (for example).

- Press **Run Script** (only need to do once)
- Enable the **Register** option in the text editor (so it runs automatically)

Here is a sample script.

```
import bpy

def stamp_set(scene):
    note =    "Samples: "         + str(scene.cycles.samples)
    note += ", ApertireBlades: "  + str(scene.camera.data.cycles.aperture_blades)
    note += ", Version: "         + bpy.app.version_string
    scene.render.stamp_note_text = note

bpy.app.handlers.render_pre.append(stamp_set)
```

To add more settings you can find the data-paths to them by right clicking and selecting **Copy Data-Path**.

[image: Stamp image]

### Global Stamp (applies to any file you render)

Having to define a script in *every-file* could be tedious, if you want to use these extra stamp options in *all* your files, you can make this a `persistent` handler.

If you want to have the same stamp notes apply to all your renders (where the **Note** is enabled). You can add the same script into your startup file and

```
@bpy.app.handlers.persistent
def stamp_set(scene):
    .... same as before ...
```

---

#### String Formatting (further reading if you're new to Python)

Python has some clever ways you can format strings, see [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html).

This uses the `format` method which some people may prefer.

```
def stamp_set(scene):
    scene.render.stamp_note_text = \
        "Samples: {samples}, Blades: {blades}, Version: {ver}".format(
        samples=scene.cycles.samples,
        blades=scene.camera.data.cycles.aperture_blades,
        ver=bpy.app.version_string,
        )
```

---

**New Lines**

As of 2.77 the note will be wrapped onto new lines, you can also add in explicit `\n` newline characters to format the text yourself.

---

**Floating point numbers**

A lot could be written on this, just a quick hint, if you have unwanted precision removed, eg:`2.514000002324` displayed as `2.51`, there are a few ways to go about it.

- If you used `"Text " + str(some.number)` you can use `round`, eg:
  `"Text " + str(round(some.number, 2))`
- If you use the `format()` method you can replace:
  `{myvar}` with `{myvar:.2f}`.

For more details see https://stackoverflow.com/a/455634/432509

Comment: Thanks for the information!
Is it possible to reduce the amount of digits for example **Aperture Size** (*scene.camera.data.cycles.aperture_size*) string returns? - 

Because number 0.55 in the DOF panel returns 0.5499997735023499

Comment: Added hint on reducing excess precision.

Comment: Is there a way to do this for values that change over time? For instance, the Lens stamp setting don't update when I change the focal length of the camera. What if I wanted to have a custom note that includes the camera's focal length and change it over time? Would that be possible?

Comment: Have a look at the different handlers, after changing the frame might be a good time to run this.

Answer (score 6):

**For Blender 2.8+**

Note that the aforementioned solutions do not seem to work in newer versions of Blender (I'm using 2.92.0, but I imagine the changes are from 2.8+).

Herewith a working solution:

```py
import bpy

cycles = bpy.context.scene.cycles
view_settings = bpy.context.scene.view_settings

def stamp_set(scene):
    note = "-------------\nCustom data\n-------------"
    note += "\nSamples: "         + str(cycles.aa_samples)
    note += "\nLook: "            + str(view_settings.look)
    note += "\nExposure: "        + str(round(view_settings.exposure, 2))

    scene.render.stamp_note_text = note

bpy.app.handlers.render_pre.append(stamp_set)
```

**This solution:**

1. Works in latest versions of Blender
2. Incorporates number rounding and newlines as per comment by [ideasman42](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/26644/26413)
3. Allows you to add new lines of data just by duplicating any of the `note += ...`  lines

**Sample output:**

[image: sample stamp output]

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old post, but I found out that in newer versions of Blender you can do exactly that.

In the **Output Properties** tab  you can burn the **metadata** into your output image, using the **Burn into image** tick.
[image: metadata]

Maybe this could help someone looking for an answer.