# Customized time stamp / clock

Tags: rendering

Is it possible to create a customized time stamp on the video? By customized I mean an arbitrary hour:minute:second that would count up time (24 fps)? The Metadata stamp is useless for this purpose, since it will stamp current system time at the end of each frame render, which depends on render time anyway.

Comment: Related http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/26644/15543

Answer (score -1):

Metadata should give the following:

- Time gives timecode as HH:MM:SS.FF (This will depend on the framerate you set in the render settings.)
- Date gives the system date and time.
- RenderTime gives the time taken to render the frame.
- Frame gives the frame number.

You could affect the timecode by sliding your scene to the desired timepoint in the VSE and render from there.

Comment: Yes, indeed, that's seems to be the easiest way without coding but Blender has a limit of starting frame at 300,000. And to achieve a time stamp of let's say 5:30, starting frame must be 475200.

Comment: You can probably rig something up with this then: https://github.com/leomoon-studios/blender-text-counter/blob/master/README.md