# Custom Render Stamp, python newline

Tags: rendering, customization

Was looking around for how to have properties from blender in the notes for the render stamp.  I found a solution although with many properties I would like to add a newline or carriage return to format the output so that I can have a block on the side of the frame rather than running the length of the frame.

Found this: [How to show render-stamp for arbitrary values?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26643/how-to-show-render-stamp-for-arbitrary-values)

The sample script in the answers Works great! A little further on the answer refers to:

> New Lines
>
> As of 2.77 the note will be wrapped onto new lines, you can also add in 
>   explicit \n newline characters to format the text yourself.

I just can't understand where and how to put that /n.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Newline using `\n`

`\n` in Python is the newline character.

Execute the lines in python.

```
import bpy
bpy.context.scene.render.stamp_note_text = "Line 1.\nLine2."
```

You will see a nondisplayable character show up in the *note* field of the stamp. (It is a newline character, which can't display in a single line textbox.) Rendering it, properly display the newline.

[image]

---

#### Automatic wrapping

> As of 2.77 the note will be wrapped onto new lines [...]

This refers to too long text snippes being automatically wrapped. A test seems to show a limit in characters though.

[image]

Comment: In the line  note  =   "Samples: "                     + str(scene.cycles.samples) I added a /n in the quotes after "Samples:/n" and I don't get a newline, just a /n.

Comment: Use a backslash! '\n' not '/n'.

Comment: works!  Thank You very much, sorry for my denseness.

Comment: @eh-five No problem, if this answer solved your problem, please mark it [as accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).