# Show time of day in render

Tags: add-on, compositing-nodes

I am using the lighting sun position add-on in Blender 2.82 to render an animation. I want the viewer of this animation to see on which time it is. I only want the hours to show.

So it should be a kind of "timer" which starts at 09.00 in the morning and ends on 20.00 in the evening. And just reads the time values in the lighting sun position add-on.[image]

I have no idea how to start with this. I have been searching for compositing settings, but i read there are no options for text in the compositing nodes.

I have also been searching for other methods and often see python codes. I have no idea how to use them, and they don't seem to do what i want.

It seems such a simple thing that i am thinking that i miss something very obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hade the same problem. I ended up using the [animation nodes](https://animation-nodes.com/) add-on with a custom expression:[image]

```
('%.2f' % (int(((math.floor(bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].sun_pos_properties.time))+(bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].sun_pos_properties.time-(math.floor(bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].sun_pos_properties.time)))*0.6)*100)/100)).zfill(5)
```

You can just rebuild the node tree and copy the expression.

Comment: Works perfect in the GUI. But it gives me problems when i use command line rendering. 
If i parent the text to an object (camera or empty) and move the object, it will not render the text after the object stops moving.
Ideal i would want to use text object output in the compositor, but i can't figure that out.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [metadata](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/output/metadata.html) to do that:

Go to the *output properties* and to the *metadata* section.

Then choose the date and activate *'burn into image'*:

[image]

You can obtain something like that:

[image]

That can also be customized using Python as described in this [answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26643/how-to-show-render-stamp-for-arbitrary-values).

Answer (score 1):

I ended up making an overlay image in photoshop. Saved it twentyfour times for each hour. And give them names from 1 to 240. This way i have one picture for every frame.

I used an image sequence in the compositing to put the images over my renders.
[image]

Comment: Were you looking after rendering metadata?

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution :). I've found [Text Counter addon](https://github.com/leomoon-studios/leomoon-textcounter) which could be useful here. And thanks for mentioning the Sun Position addon, i had no idea it works in 2.8!

Comment: @lemon Yes, something like that.

Comment: @JachymMichal. It looks like that could have been an easier solution.

Comment: @Zanzi, don't know if it is what you want, but look at the output property panel 'metadata' section and 'burn into image'.

Comment: @lemon It looks like my way, was the way with the most work. Maybe you could post this as an answer to the question. I will vote for it, because this was actually what I was searching for.