# Is there a way to show Sample Count AFTER a render has finished?

Tags: rendering

Pretty simple-
Is there any way to store/show that total Sample count once the render has finished?
I feel like that should be useful information that should remain displayed. Is there any way to retrieve that info once done with a render?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to show render-stamp for arbitrary values?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26643/how-to-show-render-stamp-for-arbitrary-values)

Comment: It's not really clear how one would do that. With adaptive sampling and time limited sampling it gets a bit more complicated.