Is there a way to tell how many samples Blender used after rendering?
When using a threashold value (and some high enough value for the samples), Blender will make the decision for you when to stop rendering to optimize render times. So far, so good.
My question is:
I'm looking for a way to see how many samples were actually used when rendering finished. I was hoping to find that in the meta data, but that is not in there (only the number of samples you entered). Any idea if that number can be found somewhere?
Thx in advance!
-B2Z

Also see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26643/how-to-show-render-stamp-for-arbitrary-values/26644#26644

@DuarteFarrajotaRamos The duplicate question you are linking to is talking about metadata. There you will only find the set max amount of samples - which B2Z explicitly says in his question is not what he wants. With Blender's adaptive sampling renders can stop before the max amount is reached, and this lower number of samples is what is asked for.

@B2Z Although this might be interesting, I doubt there is a way to find out. The way adaptive sampling in Cycles works is, areas with less noise get less samples and noisy areas get more samples. Apart from that the Noise Threshold limits the amount of samples a pixel gets as well - it always gets the amount of Min Samples, and up to the Max Samples amount unless the Time Limit or Noise Threshold is reached before that maximum. So each pixel gets its individual amount of samples, that's 2,073,600 values for a 1920 × 1080 pixel image. Is that what you want?

@GordonBrinkmann true, missed that detail. Reopened

@DuarteFarrajotaRamos Well, the duplicate might not be the answer, but given what I wrote in my second comment I do not really think he will get an answer here. This is more a question for the developers of Blender probably, but even then - I guess he expects a single sample value, but unless there is a way to calculate the average sample rate per pixel (which we as users most likely have no access to) this seems unanswerable to me., but I might be wrong. It would help if B2Z would tell us what he expects.

Some average value is probably the closest we could get, but not sure how meaningful it would be for any comparison with absolute values. Regardless it sounds like it would be a feature request then

Looks like the answer is: No, there is no way to get a single number for actual samples used because there is no such single number.
Apparently, each pixel has it's own number of samples, so any answer would be somehow statistical. I was interested in the maximum number of samples used for all pixels. Although statistical values for the samples like min, max or mean could be calculated, there doesn't seem to be any option for this in Blender.
